# UIVisualEffectView added to UICollectionViewCell visibly

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uivisualeffectview

I have `UICollectionView` with a lot of cells. The cells have images on them that need to be blurred. That's why I am adding `UIVisualEffectView` with blur effect to the `image views`. The cells are like pages - every cell takes up the whole screen.

The problem is with the second cell. When it appears the blurred view is added visibly and it's ugly. The rest of the cells have the blurred view already when they become visible on the screen and are okay. This is the code I am using to add the `blur view`:

```
class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let regularBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: regularBlur)
        blurView.frame = backgroundImageView.bounds
        blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        backgroundImageView.addSubview(blurView)

    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem might be that loading a blur for a big area of the screen needs a lot of processing so you are able to see the image before the blur is completed. Is your image fully covering the cell? If so you might want to look for an alternative solution. Like having always the blur there. Other option would be to hide the image before the blur is ready and unhide it when blur is ready.

Comment: @zero thanks for the response. Yes, the image is fully covering the cell. What do you mean by "having always the blur there"?

Comment: Having the Blur always there like having the blur on top of the collection view itself. So you only have 1 blur instead of 1 per cell. But maybe the solution would be to hide the image until the blur is loaded. What do you think ?

Comment: @zero How will I know if the blur is ready? I think I cannot have just one blur, because there is another image over the blur, that should not be blurred.

Comment: Hiding it in the awakeFromNib, will post an answer with an example code.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code:

```
class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        backgroundImageView.isHidden = true
        let regularBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: regularBlur)
        blurView.frame = backgroundImageView.bounds
        blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        backgroundImageView.addSubview(blurView)
        backgroundImageView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but I still have this issue. It is now happening not every time, but sometimes and not always on the second cell. Maybe I should make the blur in a different way, but I worry other ways are very heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can code like this:

```
class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    blurView.frame = backgroundImageView.bounds
    blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    backgroundImageView.addSubview(blurView)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
        blurView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This will hide the blur view entirely once the cell is reused and also won't solve the issue before that (I tried it). I need the blur view to be there all the time, but to be added before the cell is visible to the user. Currently in the second cell it is added with some animation visibly for the user.

Comment: I got that now. did you try add blur effect view from xib file directly?

Comment: I added it from storyboard and the result is the same.